# How to add Symbola to Overleaf v2 as not the main font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

I'm trying to migrate from Overleaf v1 to v2 to take advantage of TeXLive 2017 (compared to 2016 for v1), however Overleaf v2 doesn't include the Symbola font, which I rely on to supply occasional unicode characters, e.g., ⓧ or ⌘, and which font *is* included in v1.

I'm trying to follow the Overleaf Help document "[I have a custom font I'd like to load to my document. How can I do this?](https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this#.W05vvS2ZNGE)"

I've downloaded `Symbola.ttf` from George Douros' 
[Unicode Fonts for Ancient Scripts](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/), and I've uploaded this file to the root of my LaTeX project in Overleaf v2.

Because Symbola was built into v1, in order to render a unicode character all I had to do was a command like `\fontspec{Symbola}{\symbol{"2468}}` to get a "circled 9."

Notwithstanding that I uploaded the `Symbola.ttf` file to my Overleaf project, these commands aren't working—I'm sure because I need to tell Overleaf to look at Symbola.ttf.

The `fontspec` commands referenced in the Overleaf Help doc, e.g., `\setmainfont{[CrimsonText-Regular.ttf]}`, (or `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont`) seem aimed at fonts that you will use as your *main* fonts. Instead, I just want `\fontspec` to recognize Symbola on an ad hoc basis.

What command, or whatever incantation, should I issue to let LaTeX/Overleaf know that when I say `\fontspec{Symbola}{\symbol{"2468}}`, I want LaTeX/Overleaf to find the Symbola.ttf file in the root of my Overleaf project?

Comment: `\newfamily\symbolafont{Symbola.ttf}\newcommand*\symbola[1]{\symbolafont\symbol{#1}}` or similar? You haven't given an MWE, so this is obviously untested.

Comment: @cfr, I corrected your spelling, from `\newfamily` to `\newfontfamily`, i.e., `\newfontfamily\symbolafont{Symbola.ttf}` and that was exactly what I needed to get the Symbola font recognized.

`\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage{fontspec}`
`\newfontfamily\symbolafont{Symbola.ttf}`
`\begin{document}`
`The command key on the Macintosh is \symbolafont{⌘}.`

`A circled-9 character is: \symbolafont{\symbol{"2468}}.`
`\end{document}`

Comment: You are being too polite: I obviously misremembered the macro's name. But I'm glad it helped. (And it is true I can't spell for toffee.)

Comment: @JimRatliff You might want to make that something like `\newcommand\circ9{{\symbolafont\symbol{"2468}}\relax}`, so that it doesn’t switch the following text to Symbola or gobble up trailing spaces. (Also untested.)

Comment: @Davislor, in fact, the `fontspec` documentation, <http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#10>, addresses the "doesn't switch the following text to Symbola point" and prescribes a different solution, e.g., in `\newcommand\textnote[1]{{\notefont #1}}`, it says "Note that the double braces are intentional; the inner pair are used to to delimit the scope of the font change."

Comment: @JimRatliff I also used a second pair of braces for that. The OP definitely should. The only differences are that mine typesets a constant value rather than taking an argument, and adds `\relax` at the end.

Comment: @JimRatliff Is there some reason not to do it the standard way with the `\DeclareTextFontCommand` thing? That is, is not using this a `fontspec` thing?